# Do Cython extension types support class attributes?

Tags: python, c, class, types, cython

Python classes can have class attributes:

```
class Foo(object):
   bar = 4
```

Is there an analogous construct for defining class attributes in Cython extension types? For example, when I try to compile the following cython code

```
cdef class Foo:
    cdef int bar
    bar = 4
```

I get this error:

```
thing.c:773:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'bar'
  bar = 4;
  ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: You also need to make it public to access it from python `cdef public int bar`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wouldn't think that my use case would be considered adding attributes at run time thought. I want to define the available class attributes once at compile time.

Comment: sorry yes, was not paying attention. I have never seen a class attribute in cython.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The short answer is yes and no.

No, there is not a convenient syntactic idiom for quickly inserting a class attribute in a `cdef class`.  However ....

The whole point of `cython` is that it gives you lower level access.  The usual motive for the extra effort is performance, but you can also do `C`-like things with the extra freedom.  The difficulty is, there are many pitfalls, and in this case, you won't get pure `python` class attributes without a lot of work.  It is nevertheless pretty easy to get what you need for simple use cases.

For example, suppose I'm making some calculating engine as a class and I wish to globally set the precision of the return value for all instances.  I want a default at compile time, and from time to time I may want to adjust it lower to quickly process some trials, and then adjust it higher for my final work.  A class attribute is made to order, but you can get the functionality you need in `cython` as follows:

First, define at the module level the following:

```
cdef int _precision[1]  # storage for my class 'attribute'
_precision[0]=8         # my default value, set during compilation
```

Using an array permits us to use the `cython` idiom `precision[0]` which is equivalent to the C `*precision`.  The `cdef` name `precision` is implicitly a pointer since the data item is an array.   This permits using `cython` syntactic idioms to convert from `cython` storage locations to python references.  If all you want is a global constant that may be accessed by `cdef` code in any of the classes in the module, you are done.  If you want to use it strictly as a class attribute, you must enforce that discipline - the compiler doesn't care.

Now if you also want to adjust the value from `python` code, you will need a pair of `cdef` functions that `python` code in the module can call to access the 'attribute':

```
cdef int*  get_precision(): return _precision
cdef void* set_precision(int i): _precision[0]=i
```

At this point, the semantics will vary a bit from pure `python`, unless you really want to sweat.  You need a `python` setter and getter function, and I find the `python` descriptor protocol implemented by properties is easiest:

```
cdef class SomeCalculator:
  ...

  property precision:
    def __get__(self):
      """Get or set calculation precision, default == 8.
         This is like a class attribute: setting affects all instances,
         however, it also affects all subclasses."""
      return get_precision()[0]
    def __set__(self,int integer): set_precision(min(30,max(0,integer)))
```

The first gets a python reference to the 'attribute'.  The second sets the 'attribute' with a `python` integral value, policed to fall within limits.  The `cython` function call and return interface automatically takes care of conversions, which are more complex than they look.

For example, `get_precision` returns a `C-pointer`.  If you did the dereferencing in `get_precision` you would get an error trying to return a `C-int` in `__get__` as if it were `python`.  If instead you just omitted the `[0]` dereference in `__get__` you would get an error trying to return a `C-pointer` as if it were a `python int`.  As written, automatic conversions correctly match types.  `cython` is very finicky about this sort of thing, and can silently return incorrect values, discoverable only at runtime.  It can take some experimentation to infer the correct incantation.

The docstring tells you not to expect a pure `python` class attribute.  If you want to sub-class, and have sub-classes use a different global setting, you will need to sweat a bit more.  In `python`, all that is done automatically.

Even so, there are other differences.  A real class attribute may be referenced on the class or on an instance.  This property may only be referenced on an instance.  Setting a real class attribute on the instance creates an instance specific copy, leaving the class attribute untouched, but invisible to the altered instance.

For the given use case, this works.  A real class attribute is unnecessary.  Since `cython` code is usually less abstract and compute intensive, this minimal approach is often enough.

Comment: Can we define a class in the usual Python manner i.e class CameraPose but then define cpdefs for inner methods for speed gains?

Answer (score 7):

While it doesn't seem to be possible to have C-typed static attributes, Cython extension types can have regular Python static attributes which are also automatically accessible in Python. Just declare them as you would declare them in Python:

```py
cdef class Foo:
    bar = 4
```

The generated code shows that these static attributes are stored as Python objects in the attribute dict of the class object, i.e. if you use them in contexts where C-types are used, they are converted back from Python objects.

Comment: In fact, I suspect nothing resembling a static class attribute is possible in cpython *except* as an element of it's `__dict__`;  compare: `type("MyType", (type,), {'__slots__':('foo',)})`

Comment: seemingly these are read-only. Is there any way to make class attributes in a Cython extension publicly accessible?

Comment: define a getter and setter for them

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that that way. I don't know whether static attributes are supported, but the "normal" ones have to be accessed from methods, e.g. a constructor:

```
cdef class Foo:
    cdef int bar
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 4
```