# How to add a static member to a Cython class (from python, not C)

Tags: python, c, class, static, cython

How would I add a static, *typed* member to a cython class? The syntax for adding typed *instance*-members uses the syntax as follows (e.g.):

```
import cython

cdef class NoStaticMembers:

   cdef public int instanceValue # but, how do I create a static member??

   def __init__(self, int value):
       self.instanceValue = value
```

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749209/do-cython-extension-types-support-class-attributes/28770515#28770515

Comment: @cel that is related but it doesn't appear they solved it either.

Comment: You seem to assume that this must be possible. I am not so sure about that.

Comment: it compiles to C, it must be. C has static class members.

Comment: You cannot make that conclusion. Cython code is translated to C, but to make that conclusion you assume that every valid c program is also valid cython code. And it's pretty obvious that this is not the case.

Comment: Also, `C` is not object-oriented, so what exactly is a `static class member` in `C`?

Comment: @cel when I said 'it has to be' I meant that it is an obvious feature that could be implemented in cython based on C++... Possibly I'll have to add the ugly hack myself to the translated C code to get it to work, but that seems to be. Also Yes, I was confusing C and C++. You're right C structs have no static members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because you can do it in C really doesn't mean you can do it in Cython.

A workround might involve using global variables, and class properties so you can access them through class instances. I'm not sure if it's really better than using global variables though

```
import cython

cdef int MyClass_static_variable

cdef class MyClass:
   property static_variable:
      def __get__(self):
         return MyClass_static_variable

      def __set__(self, x):
         global MyClass_static_variable
         MyClass_static_variable = x
```

You'd have to measure how much speed you lost through that method (and maybe consider making `__get__` and `__set__` `cpdef` if you can - I'm not sure). The only thing that doesn't let you do that a genuine static variable does is to access it as `MyClass.static_variable`.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround (with a nested class, which is a specific kind of class attribute):

```
from cpython.object cimport PyTypeObject, PyObject
from cpython.dict cimport PyDict_SetItem

cdef class Test1:
    pass

cdef class Test2:
    pass

# Building something close to:
#
# class Test1:
#     class Test2:
#         pass

PyDict_SetItem(<object>(<PyTypeObject*>Test1).tp_dict, 'Test2', Test2)
del globals()['Test2']
```

Which seems to work (the exception is expected):

```
>>> import mymodule
>>> mymodule.Test1
<class 'mymodule.Test1'>
>>> mymodule.Test2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'mymodule' has no attribute 'Test2'
>>> mymodule.Test1.Test2
<class 'mymodule.Test2'>
```

I'm using a nested class here, but it could be anything.

It's not 100% clean:

- I would have expected `<class 'mymodule.Test1.Test2'>` as a result to my last query (could be fixed, but do we want more tricks?)
- Modifying tp_dict after PyType_Ready is not clean (is it?). But, in our specific use case, I think it doesn't matter.