# Mixing cdef and regular python attributes in cdef class

Tags: python, cython

i am learning Cython and now experimenting with it. I tried the basic cdef class sample program and it works perfectly.

Now what i want to do is have a mix of cdef and non cdef mix of attributes in the cdef class type, something like this

```
cdef class Context:
    cdef public int byteIndex, bitIndex

    def __init__(self, msg = "", msg_len = 0):
        self.msg = msg 
        self.msg_len = msg_len 
        self.byteIndex = 0
        self.bitIndex = 7
```

but as soon as i instantiate the object i get error

`!! AttributeError: 'c_asnbase.Context' object has no attribute 'msg'`

Does this mean once you define a python class with cdef all self.* attributes have to be cdef defined?

Comment: "Now what i want to do is have a mix of cdef and non cdef mix of attributes" - why?

Comment: because i feel string like attributes are easier to handle in python. so wondering if i can keep string attributes in python and convert only numeric attributes to cdef.

Comment: "i feel string like attributes are easier to handle in python" - cdef isn't going to stop Python from accessing your attributes. You marked them public, after all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Does this mean once you define a python class with cdef all self.* attributes have to be cdef defined?

Yes. This is stated pretty explicitly in [the documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html):

> Attributes in cdef classes behave differently from attributes in regular classes:
>
> - All attributes must be pre-declared at compile-time
> - ...

You can quite happily store a string by defining the attribute to be of type object:

```
cdef public object msg
```

---

Internally, the reason for this is that the `cdef class` does not have a dictionary, which saves space and makes attribute access faster, but it does mean that it cannot have arbitrary attributes added at runtime. This is reasonably similar to using `__slots__` in a normal Python class.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28749209/1959808

Comment: @DavidW can i have `public:` to define a section of public attributes?

Comment: @datdinhquoc I don't think so, but it's very easy for you to try it and see if it works

Answer (score 8):

As @DavidW has pointed out, the problem of cdef-classes is that they have no `__dict__`. You can add `__dict__` to the class-definition, if really desired:

```
%%cython
cdef class A:
    cdef dict __dict__        # now the usual attribute look-up is possible
    cdef readonly int answer 
    def __init__(self):
        self.answer = 42             #cdef attribute
        self.question = "unknown"    #pure python attribute, possible
```

And now:

```
a=A()
print(a.answer)
# 42
print(a.question)
# 'unknown' 
a.question = 'Why?'
print(a.question)
# 'Why?' 
setattr(a, 'new_attr', None)
print(a.new_attr)
# None
```

Note: `setattr(a,'new_attr', None)` would be not possible if `cdef class A` were defined without `__dict__`, but with `cdef public object question` instead.

Obviously there are additional cost using `__dict__`, so probably one would use the predefined attributes whenever the performance matters. 
One of advantages of cdef-classes is smaller memory-footprint (for example because there is no `__dict__`-slot). So adding `__dict__`-slot would negate at least some of advantages - one should ask, whether another design would be a better option - but there are obviously scenarios, where adding `__dict__`-slot makes sense.

Another way would be to create a subclass of the `cdef class` and use it rather than the base-class.

---

Once the `__dict__` slot is defined, instances of class `A` have the`__dict__`-attribute (which is not the case for usual `cdef`-classes). However,  `__dict__` doesn't contain `cdef`-attributes, e.g. `answer` from the example above (no matter whether they are public or not) - only the normal pure python attributes (e.g. `question` and `new_attr` in the example above).

Here for the example above:

```
# no answer-attribute in __dict__:
a.__dict__
# {'new_attr': None, 'question': 'Why?'}
```

---

NB: [here is the part](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#dynamic-attributes) in the Cython-documentation about dynamic attributes.