# how to add attribute to existing class in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, cython, pyx

I trying to edit sklearn and I need to add an attribute for one of the class.
I was sure that adding `self.attribute`  will be the answer but i keep getting an error this attribute isn't available. I try to add this attribute install the new package with my change and everything went fine until I run it

```py
cdef class ClassificationCriterion(Criterion):
    """Abstract criterion for classification."""

    def __cinit__(self, SIZE_t n_outputs,
                  np.ndarray[SIZE_t, ndim=1] n_classes, int test = 1):
        """Initialize attributes for this criterion.

        Parameters
        ----------
        n_outputs : SIZE_t
            The number of targets, the dimensionality of the prediction
        n_classes : numpy.ndarray, dtype=SIZE_t
            The number of unique classes in each target
        """
        self.test = test
```

code I ran:

```py
clf = sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy',random_state=0,max_depth=2 )
clf2=clf.fit(x,y)
```

> AttributeError: sklearn.tree._criterion.Entropy object has no attribute test

Comment: Can't you make a subclass it instead of editing the source code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixing cdef and regular python attributes in cdef class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632297/mixing-cdef-and-regular-python-attributes-in-cdef-class)