# ValueError: Does not understand character buffer dtype format string ('w')

Tags: python, cython

I have a list that I am trying to pass from python to cython.

The list called `instruments` looks like:

```
['BBG.XASX.ABC.S' 'BBG.XTKS.9987.S' 'BBG.XTKS.9984.S' 'BBG.XTKS.9991.S'
 'BBG.XTKS.9989.S' 'BBG.XTKS.9983.S' 'BBG.XTKS.9997.S' 'BBG.XTKS.9974.S']
```

and has a type: `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

The error that I am getting is:

```
  File "project/dept.pyx", line 36, in project.dept.SimSettings.__cinit__
ValueError: Does not understand character buffer dtype format string ('w')
```

The research I have conducted suggests that if I want to use a Python list in Cython I have to convert the list to unicode objects in my Cython code so I have tried changing the list to a unicode format using:

```
instruments = np.array(instruments,dtype=np.unicode)
```

However this does not fix the issue.

I note that the error is around a lower case `w`, however my list does not contain a lower case w so this is adding to my confusion.

The code I have is:

opt.py

```
instruments = np.array(instruments,dtype=np.unicode)

sim_settings=SimSettings(            
        dept_max=5.0,
        dept_min=2.0,
        margin=0.05,
        cost=1,
        stocks=instruments,
        dept_median=4.4,
        time_loss=5)
```

dept.pyx

```
cdef class SimSettings:
    def __cinit__(self,
                  double dept_max,
                  double dept_min,
                  double margin,
                  bint cost,
                  str[:] instruments,
                  double dept_median,
                  int time_loss):
```

Comment: Note that `str[:]` definitely doesn't match what you pass it - it's essentially a memoryview of Python objects. I'd personally leave `instruments` untyped so that it accepts any Python object (i.e. a `list`!), but if you really want to do it with Cython then the duplicate question tells you how to access it as numeric data.

Comment: Hi DavidW thanks - I removed the type str[:] but now I get an AttributeError: 'project.dept.SimSettings' object has no attribute 'instruments' - any thoughts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632297/mixing-cdef-and-regular-python-attributes-in-cdef-class?rq=1 - you can't just set attributes by assigning to a `cdef class` instance. You need to statically type them (probably just as `cdef instruments` to accept any Python object).