# Cython subclassing "First base of" ... "is not an extension type" even though it is defined with cdef

Tags: python, cython, subclassing, cythonize

I am working with Cython to optimize my Python code for a university project.
To do that I want to transform python classes into extension types. I currently have issues compiling one extension type which *should* be a subclass of another extension type.
This is the error I get:

```
src/core/ast/ast_classes/AstPreprocessor.pyx:9:27: First base of 'AstPreprocessor' is not an extension type
```

The definition of AstPreprocessor is as follows:

```
#Edit
from src.core.ast.ast_classes.AstBase import AstBase

cdef class AstPreprocessor(AstBase):
    cdef str function_name

    def __init__(self, function_ast, str function_name):
        super().__init__(function_ast)
        self.ast.index = self.ast.index.map(str)
        self.function_name = function_name
        self.symbol_list = super().get_symbol_list(self.function_name)

    #more method declarations
```

Here is part of the AstBase class including the method called in `AstPreprocessor#__init__()`:

```
cdef class AstBase:
    cdef int length
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.ast = df
        self.length = int(df.shape[0])
        self.childrens = {}

    #more method declarations    

    cdef get_symbol_list(self, str function_name):
        symbol_list = []
        for i in self.ast.index:
            i = int(i)
            if self.token(i).startswith('SYMBOL') \
                    and self.text(i) != function_name:
                symbol_list.append(i)
        return symbol_list
```

Here is the cythonize command from my setup.py:

```
ext_modules=cythonize(["src/core/ast/ast_classes/*.pyx",
                       "src/core/ast/preprocessing/*.pyx"], 
                       language_level=3, annotate=True),
```

I have looked inside the docs but I have a hard time really understanding why this error occurs and how to fix it. This is the first time I am using Cython thus any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
I also tried using cimport but sadly the problem did not change.

Comment: It's difficult to be sure without an actual [mre] but I guess you have to `cimport AstBase` rather than `import` it. That lets Cython work out the type at compile-time

Comment: @DavidW Unfortunately that did not work, furthermore I added the original import statement. Thank you for the answer! 
Concerning the minimal reproducible example: I have tested it only using the code I provided. Unfortunately the error still persists. You can try by copy/pasting what I did and editing the import of `AstPreprocessor`. You should get exactly the same error.

Comment: If there is no pxd-file, cimport will not work.

Comment: Related piece of documentation: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html

Comment: @ead thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do 2 things. [First create a .pxd file](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pxd_files.html) for `AstBase` called `AstBase.pxd`. These act sort of like C headers and are used to share Cython declarations between different modules. It should contain

```
cdef class AstBase:
    cdef int length
    # any other cdef attributes

    cdef get_symbol_list(self, str function_name)
    # but not the implementation of get_symbol_list
```

Your `AstBase.pyx` file looks substantially the same:

```
cdef class AstBase:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.ast = df
        self.length = int(df.shape[0])
        self.childrens = {}
```

Note that I've removed `length` since it's declared in the pxd. Be aware [that all attributes will need to be declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632297/mixing-cdef-and-regular-python-attributes-in-cdef-class) - currently `ast` and `childrens` aren't.

Then in `AstPreprocessor.pyx` you need to `cimport` rather than `import` `AstBase`

```
from AstBase cimport AstBase

# the rest stays the same
```

This ensures that Cython knows the details of the class (including the fact that it's a `cdef class`) at compile time. Typically if Cython doesn't know the details of an object it assumes that it's a regular Python object that'll be available at runtime, and this sometimes leads to confusing error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will make the necessary changes.